# How to get fake debts legally quashed?

Tags: finance, debt

Consider the situation where a company claims someone owes them money. The person disavows this debt and believes it is falsely assigned to them.

Further, assume the company sells the debt to a debt collector or lists the debt as unpaid to a credit reporting agency.

Is there any legal remedy for the person who does not actually owe any money?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: The United States

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/50193/apartment-i-never-lived-in-is-collecting-against-me-recourse

http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/what-happens-if-a-collector-doesnt-respond-to-a-debt-validation-request

http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/how-to-get-rid-of-someone-elses-debt-collector

http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23718/how-do-i-deal-with-a-collection-agent-who-refused-to-state-a-reason-for-calling

Comment: [Great answer here](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/14701/10).